# Testing the apex class which implements Comparable

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup

How can I test the below test class? Any thing to get me started?

```
global with sharing Class FieldSetDetail implements Comparable
{
    global String fieldSetName {get; public set;}
    global String sectionLabel {get; public set;}
    global String RecordTypeName {get; public set;}
    global Integer Columns {get; public set;}
    global Decimal Order {get; public set;}
    global Map<String, String> otherAttributes {get; public set;}
    global List<fieldSetMemberDetail> fields {get; public set;}

    private static Map<String, Schema.sObjectField> fieldMap;

    global Integer compareTo(Object obj) 
    {

        FieldSetDetail fsd=(FieldSetDetail)obj;
        try
        {
            return Integer.valueOf(this.Order)-Integer.valueOf(fsd.Order);
        }
        Catch(Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void init(Schema.FieldSet fieldSet, Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResult)
    {
        this.fieldSetName = fieldSet.getName();
        if(this.Columns == NULL || this.Columns < 1 || this.Columns > 2)
            this.Columns = 2;
        if(fieldMap == NULL)
            fieldMap=describeSObjectResult.fields.getMap();
        this.fields= new List<FieldSetMemberDetail>();
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSetMember: fieldSet.getFields())
        {
            FieldSetMemberDetail fsmd=new FieldSetMemberDetail();
            fsmd.fieldName=fieldSetMember.getFieldPath();
            fsmd.isRequired =fieldSetMember.getRequired();
            try
            {
                if(fieldMap.get(fieldSetMember.getFieldPath().toLowerCase()).getDescribe().isAccessible())
                    this.fields.add(fsmd);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    global Class fieldSetMemberDetail
    {
        global String fieldName {get;set;}
        global Boolean isRequired {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you test any other class...<strike>try to take over the world</strike>, create a test to call a particular method, and set up data so that you exercise each of the paths (or, at least, enough of them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a list of a few instances, sort it, then verify the results. Something like:

```
FieldSetDetail[] details = new FieldSetDetail[0];
for(Integer index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    details.add(new FieldSetDetail());
    details[index].Order = Math.random();
}
details.sort();
for(Integer index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    System.assert(details[index].Order < details[index+1].Order);
}
```

Comment: It's important to test edge cases here. In this case, you should definitely include some with `Order = null`, since it doesn't appear to be set in the code and is not `final`. In fact, it's `public set`, so you could even consider it *likely* a given collection of this object will contain such an instance. I think the pokemon catch is kind of broken in this regard, though I'm not sure what effect it has.